# JSF & Webflow - <h:selectManyListbox> converting troubles

Tags: java, jsf, spring-webflow

In JSF, I have this:

```
<h:selectManyListbox id="createAccountBasicInfo_select_Types"
 styleClass="selectManyCheckbox" value="#{party.roles}" size="6"
 converter="persistenceObjectToStringTwoWayConverter">
      <f:selectItems value="#{accTypes.selectItems}" />
</h:selectManyListbox>
```

My Converter:

```
 //[...]
 import javax.faces.convert.Converter;
 //[...]

public class PersistenceObjectToStringJSFConverter implements Converter {
    //[...]

public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
    Long id = Long.valueOf(value);
    Object object = null;
    try {
        object = getPersistenceService(context).loadByEntityId(id); // here I load the appropriate record
    } catch (CoreException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ElementCreationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return object; //here I need to return an ArrayList of the loaded Objects instead of a single object
}
 }
```

In HTML, I get this:

```
<select id="form_party:createAccountBasicInfo_select_Types"
 name="form_party:createAccountBasicInfo_select_Types" class="selectManyCheckbox" 
 multiple="multiple" size="6"> 
  <option value="171128">Andere</option>
  <option value="171133">Interessent</option>
  <option value="171130">Kunde</option>
  <option value="171131">Lieferant</option>
  <option value="171134">Mitarbeiter</option>
  <option value="171132">Mitbewerber</option>
  <option value="171129">Partner</option>
</select>
```

The value of each option is an Id, which I have to load from the database.
An ArrayList of the selected entries will then be given to the WebFlow and then saved to the database.

When I press my "save" button, the selected items run through a Converter, where I need to load the items from the database (by value, ex. "171128") and add it to an ArrayList, which will be inserted into "party.roles" (check JSF Code).

My problem:
I'm getting the following JSF Exception:

`/WEB-INF/page/core/fragments/account/accountBasicInfo.xhtml @152,58 value="#{party.roles}": Property 'roles' not writable on type java.util.List`

I think there is a problem with my Converter. What do I have to change?

Thank's for you anwsers!

(I'm using JSF 1.2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception is telling that `#{party}` is actually a `java.util.List` which in turn indeed doesn't have a `setRoles()` method so the `#{party.roles}` ain't going to work.

The `#{party}` should be a managed bean and it should have a `private List<Role> roles` property with a getter. The converter should not return a `List<Role>` on the `getAsObject()` but it should return `Role`.

Comment: Party is a single Object, generated with JAXB. There are getters and setters for each Property, so there is also one for "roles". The "roles" Property is a List<Role>. So I don't think that's the solution.

Comment: I updated the answer a bit after reading the comment in the return line of your `getAsObject()` method. Returning a `List<Role>` instead of `Role` based on the given unique id is definitely wrong.